# How to creat an auto-advance feature with PHP/XML

Tags: php, xml

I know how to read and parse XML with PHP, but is there a way to make it auto advance through pages of XML data automatically?  I work for a TV station that is featuring open houses via a real estate xml feed and need to show one or two houses at a time for a half hour without requiring someone to sit there and advance the pages themselves.  Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Advance what page? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You could have PHP output the necessary JavaScript to redirect to the next page.

Here's how to redirect to a new page: [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093) combine that with [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) to add a delay.

I'm not sure whether I would rely on this for a live TV feed, though - I'd be too scared of the embarrassment of the browser crashing, or an error popping up....

Comment: LOL!  Luckily it's all pre-recorded so the finished product woul dbe checked before hand...thanks for the tip!  I'll look into the javascript solution.